# What are the ways to find the session leader or the controlling TTY of a process group in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, go

This is not a language specific question, although I am using golang at the moment.

I am writing a command line program, and I wanted to find the real UID of the program.(By realUID, I meant, if the user did a sudo, the effective uid changes, but the real uid would be the same as the user's.)

- I've read that finding the owner of the controlling tty is one way to find this, and on linux, we can use "tty" command, that will return the filename of the terminal connected to STDINPUT. Checking its ownership is one way.
- Another way is to find the session leader process, and who owns it.

I tried the first way, using

```
cmdOut []byte
cmdOut, _ = exec.Command("tty").Output()
```

but it returns the output `not a tty`, when I run the program from my shell. Chances are that this might be getting executed in a separate forked shell that is detached from a tty (again, just a wild guess).

I tried the second way using `os.Getppid()` to get the parent pid, but in reality, when running sudo, it forks again, and it is giving the parent pid of the sudo process(`16031` in the below case, whereas I am looking to grab `3393` instead.). (Pasting the process hierarchy from pstree output)
`/usr/bin/termin(3383)-+-bash(3393)---sudo(16031)---Myprogram(16032)`, so effectively I am not able to get the session leader process, but just the parent pid.

Can someone guide me on how do I implement this functionality using either of this method?

Comment: Take a look at manpage: `man 7 credentials`. There is section `User and group identifiers`.

Comment: Can't you just use `getuid()`?

Comment: @SergeyKanaev Thank you, let me explore the options of that, and if I can do it with a syscall, probably that will help.

Comment: @IanAbbott Nope. That will get you the effective uid, and that changes when you use sudo. I wanted to get the real uid.

Answer (score 2):

Edit:
sudo set's `$SUDO_USER` environment variable, but it will help just with one sudo, i.e. if there was something like `sudo sudo -u nobody your-program`, `$SUDO_USER` will be set to "root". And there is `$SUDO_UID` too.

Old answer: How about `exec.Command("who am i").Output()` ? (won't work, still needs a tty).

Comment: That will get you the effective uid, not the real uid. To get that, I can just use  `os.Getuid`.

Comment: Are you shure? When i'm running `sudo id` it will show roots id, but if i run `sudo who am i` it shows the id of user who actually did run sudo, even through a chain of different sudos.

Comment: Yep. Checked it.
`[scott@workbench scripts]$ sudo whoami
root
[scott@workbench scripts]$ whoami
scott`

Comment: Not `whoami`, as i wrote `who am i` with spaces.

Comment: It works in cmd, but as I mentioned with the command `tty`, Chances are that this might be getting executed in a separate forked shell that is detached from a tty (again, just a wild guess) and doesn't return a value when put inside a program,

Comment: That changes to `root` when we do sudo.

Comment: $SUDO_USER will help if it's only one sudo, but it's not a good solution.

Comment: Yes it is not reliable. They are not set on these servers :(